# content inside :before gets hidden when setting overflow to scroll/hidden

Tags: jquery, html, css

Following is my code for a simple navigation. I have two div that appear when clicked on the icon at the top right corner. I also have a triangular tip for these divisions at the top implemented using `:before`.
For the first div i have set `overflow:scroll` so , the triangular tip is not visible. In the second case it is visible since i have not set the overflow property.
Is there any work around to show the triangular tip , but also set the overflow property?

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
   
   $('html').click(function() {
    $(".grid1").hide();
   $(".grid2").hide();

});
$( ".icons-container i" ).click(function() {
  
  event.stopPropagation();
  if(this.id=="grid1icon")
  {
   
   $(".grid1").show();
   $(".grid2").hide();

  }
  else if(this.id=="grid2icon")
  {
   
   $(".grid2").show();
   $(".grid1").hide();
  }
});
});
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";

body {


 }

 .nav-container
 {
  height: 50px;
 }

 .logo
 {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  background: #ccc;
  height: 100%;
 }
 .searchboxcontianer
 {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  background: #555;
  
 }
.searchbox
{
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-top: 1.3%;
  position: relative;
}
 .searchinput
 {
  width: 400px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 2px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 3px 0px 0px 3px;
 }

 .searchbutton 
 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 34px;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  outline: none;
  margin-left: -4px;
  top:0px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 0px 3px 3px 0px;
  
 }
 .nav-icons
 {
  width: 29%;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  background: #444;
 }

 .icons-container
 {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  padding: 5px 0px;
 }

  .icons-container i 
  {
    margin: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
  }

  .grid1
  {
   position: absolute;
   top:60px;
   right: 40px;
   background: #eee;
   height: 300px;
   width: 250px;  
   border-radius: 5px;
   border: solid 2px #555;
   display: none;
   overflow-y: scroll;
  }

  .grid1 ul
  {
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  .grid1 ul li 
  {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #444;
    margin: 2px;
  }

  .grid1:before
  {
    border: solid;
    border-color: #000 transparent;
    border-width: 0px 6px 6px 6px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -7px;
    right: 150px;
    z-index: 99;
    content: ""
  }
  .grid2 
  {
position: absolute;
   top:60px;
   right: 10px;
   background: #eee;
   height: 300px;
   width: 250px;  
   border-radius: 5px;
   border: solid 2px #555;display: none;
  }

  .grid2:before 
  {
    border: solid;
    border-color: #000 transparent;
    border-width: 0px 6px 6px 6px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -7px;
    right: 150px;
    z-index: 99;
    content: ""

  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav-container">

 <div class="logo">
  Logo goes in here
 </div>
 <div class="searchboxcontianer">
  <div class="searchbox">
   <input type="text" class="searchinput" name="search" id="search">
   <button class="searchbutton"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
  </div>

 </div>
 <div class="nav-icons">
  <div class="icons-container">
  <i id="grid1icon" class="fa fa-th"></i>
  <div class="grid1">
   some content goes in here
   <ul>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <i id="grid2icon" class="fa fa-bell"></i>
  <div class="grid2">
      some othe content goes in here
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Please check the code snippet in full page view.

Comment: @connexo something similar to a tooltip. At the top right of each division that appears on clicking the icons.

Comment: You need the overflow property to make the div scrollable, right?

Comment: Overflow scroll is working fine. But when applying that property the triangular tip at the top ( which is positioned outside the div using `:before` ) is also getting hidden.

Comment: To fix that, proceed as I suggest in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put another container inside your menu container, and apply overflow to that. Apply the `:before` triangle on the outer container which has fixed width/height.